Login route issue comparing password
//login route
router.post('/login', async(req,res) =>{
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({username});
        if(!user){
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'user does not exist' });
        }
        
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (passwordMatch) {
            res.json({ success: true, user });
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Incorrect password' });
        }        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error logging in:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Server error' });
    }
});

with the login route, I am not able to compare the password of the user. Even if the password is correct, the backend response is always 'incorrect password'.
//frontend code for handling login
    const handleLogin = async() =>{
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://my-backend-url/api/login', {
                username,
                password
            });

            if(response.data.success===true){
                dispatch(setUser(response.data.user));
                navigation.navigate("Home");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setErrorMessage(error.response?.data?.message || "login failed");
        }
    }

I need to login user to my app using password. I have no idea where I am going wrong with this one.
